# Stretch WrapGrid item width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am using a `WrapGrid` as `itemscontrol` in a `ListView` to present items horizontally with following XAML code (WinRT)

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate >
    <WrapGrid x:Name="ContentGrid" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5" >                                     
    </WrapGrid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Now how can i **stretch items horizontally** when the width is more than `MinWidth` and No More items can be added Horizontally. (All the items are aligned to center and there are lots of space in both sides horizontally)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomChildItemTemplete">
   <Grid Background="Red">
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate >
```

**More Details:**  When the `listview` width is Around 800 (approx) it is showing 4 items horizontal (as minimum item width is 200) but if the width is 900 (4 items visible) and blank space (50 px) is in Right and Left of the `itemscontrol`, how can i remove this blank space by increasing the item width (simply item width must be 225 when `listview` width is 900)

Comment: I don't understand your problem very well. Maybe a screenshot of your result could be usefull ?

Comment: Is this dynamic (the size of your ItemsControl change, or it's automatically set by the layout), or do you set the width or your itemsControl yourself ?

Comment: @NicolasVoron, automatically set by the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Easiest way is to bind `MinWidth` like this :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl">
  <ItemsPanelTemplate >
      <WrapGrid x:Name="ContentGrid" MinWidth="{Binding Path=Width,  MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticRessource Myconverter}, ConverterParameter=[Here Nb of object that you want in one line]}" MinHeight="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5" >                                     
      </WrapGrid>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the converter just divide the width of your itemsControl by the parameter (Nb of object that you want in one line). So the objects are automatically at the size that you want !

Comment: I don't test this code, so it maybe don't work "as is", but the idea is this. you can try instead with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`, which works on wpf, but not tested with winRT

Comment: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}` seems to work with winRT

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand :/

Comment: Works after modiying the code with MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, I can accept your answer if you can edit it with this code, thank u very much

Comment: Does anyone know how to do the same in UWP if the original Width of the containing object is set to `"Auto"`?